# Solr Facet Range Search by Date with Intermediate Sums

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 3.6.0 and am using facet range searches by date to find out how many **invoices (my type of document)** I have in a certain time interval:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.range=invoiceDate&f.invoiceDate.facet.range.start=2012-03-01T00:00:00Z&f.invoiceDate.facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY&f.invoiceDate.facet.range.end=2012-06-01T00:00:00Z`

I get answers like this -- the quantity of individual *invoices* on each day.

```
...
<int name="2012-05-22T00:00:00Z">2</int>
<int name="2012-05-23T00:00:00Z">1</int>
<int name="2012-05-24T00:00:00Z">0</int>
...
```

This works well. Now I would like to be able to sum up the amount ("invoiceAmount") of the *invoices* within each of my date intervals. Is there anyway I can sum over another field within each date range?

Comment: [Stats component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent) does facets. I havent tried it, and I (wildly) guess there are performance issues involved.

Comment: I looked into this and there is no way to take stats of the individual intervals within the range. The stats are over the entire range.

Comment: I happned to see this: _ stats.facet: Return sub results for values within the given facet. _ and it seems similar to a regular facet.query